# Override raw_input to get answer from remote client

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to override the standard `raw_input` so I can have a "remote raw_input".

What I need is to implement this `overriden raw_input` so when I use it on my server, it will open a message box in the remote client's computer and wait for his answer. After getting the response, I'll then be able to continue with my program.

I've been searching a lot about how I can do this, but I'm a little lost mostly because I'm new to python.

And I have to do this with `raw_input`, is that possible? Can someone give me a little guidance?

UPDATE:

One good example of what I'm trying to achieve is how Jupyter handles raw_inputs.

In this notebook I simply run a raw_input, then Jupyter creates a textbox and waits for my answer:

[image: Jupyter textbox]

And then after I type my answer it goes on with the code:

[image: Jupyter textbox2]

So how does Jupyter get 'in the middle' of the raw_input to create a textbox and wait for the user input?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding builtins is, generally, not recommended for a number of reasons. Instead, try something like the following, using `receive_input` instead of `raw_input`.

```
SERVER = 1
CLI    = 2
...
config.input_type = CLI # in cli code, or SERVER in server code
...
def receive_input(cfg):
    if cfg.input_type == CLI:
        return raw_input()
    elif cfg.input_type == SERVER:
        # retrieve from somewhere else
```

Jupyter likely scans the AST of the input for `raw_input` called as a function and replaces that with their implementation.